# Drop down menu with fadeIn not working?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple drop down menu and would like the drop down to fade in and fade out, but the code I use doesn't seem to work. Not sure if I'm trying to hit the wrong selector or if the code is wrong. I'm going to say... code is wrong.

HTML:

```
<ul class="m-nav">
   <li><a href="">Rules</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Regulators</a>
      <ul class="drop">
         <li><a href="">Bobby</a></li>
         <li><a href="">David</a>
      </ul>
   <li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('ul.m-nav li').addClass('booze');

    $('.booze').hover(function() {
        $('.drop').fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $('.drop').fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

Comment: Did any of these answers help you? Let us know by an upvote or correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing an ending  tag here:

`<li><a href="">David</a>`

I added that tag, then adjusted your jQuery to look for a specific text within your `<li>`. Otherwise, the scrip will bind the `hover` event to each of your `<li>`s.

Lastly, `hide()` the dropdown initially.

It seems to be working fine for me now. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eV9Wv/

Comment: notice something odd. When you hover in and hover out of the select menu item, the drop down does a fade in and out(almost like a blinking effect) before fading in completely. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Strange. I made an edit to the fiddle yesterday, but I guess it never saved. I adjusted the last `<li>` tag to be a closing `</li>` tag. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/eV9Wv/2/

Comment: Other than that, it could probably be hovering over multiple times (accidentally or knowingly), which would trigger the animation multiple times. When you turn this setup into a full functioning nav, you shouldn't run into this issue with a large enough area to roll over.

Comment: Tested it out and the same problem still arises. The flash before it fades in. Not sure if you're getting the same problem. Hover in the word 'Regulators' and move it while hovered... and the drop down flashes before stopping.

Comment: Cool. I definitely appreciate the time and your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your selector for hover covers more that one LI, so you should fade only child .drop:

```
 $('.booze').hover(function() {
        $('.drop',this).fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $('.drop',this).fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

[Test here](http://jsbin.com/egecog/1/edit)